# Return result from a Fragment to his Activity hosting

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have a Fragment hosted in an Activity.

In the Activity i have a list of categorized items. By clicking a button, a Fragment opens and there i have a list of all categories.

The user can select an item, than by clicking a button inside the Fragment, this once must pass the result to his hosting Activity and close itself.

The main problem is that i have to create a "modular" way to do this, so i can't use something like `mActivity.category = "123"` or call a method inside the Activity like `mActivity.setCategory("123")`.

Is there a way to pass the result data like the system `onActivityResult` / `startActivityForResult` does, applyed to Activity -> Fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, check [this callback example](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity). You could also use [Intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), but callbacks should be ok for you.